# Chess Bishop movement pattern validation

Tags: algorithm, validation, chess

I understand that `abs(srcX-dstX) == abs(srcY-dstY)` is a correct validation for the movement pattern of the bishop piece.

But I would like to know if my validation is also correct, here it is:
`srcX-srcY == dstX-dstY || srcX+srcY == dstX+dstY`

If your answer is no, please specify why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its correct. The basic [method](http://www.umsl.edu/~defreeseca/intalg/ch2extra/absequ.htm) is to take original equation and remove the absolute value and then do the same but multiply by -1 on one side so

```
Given: abs(srcX-dstX) == abs(srcY-dstY)
srcX-dstX == srcY-dstY OR srcX-dstX == -srcY+dstY
```

This can be rearranged to look like yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
abs(x) =
    x if x >= 0
   -x if x < 0
```

Therefore, your validation should be :

```
  srcX-dstX == srcY-dstY ||  -srcX+dstX == srcY-dstY
```

EDIT : correction on the formulae

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to what OP wrote?